# Change Shape of constraintlayout in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

Im trying to change shape of root constraintlayout in my fragment.
like below image, to place my close button on right top corner. Is it possible in android?
[constraintlayout shape image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I6JO.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just have a white background of the parent constraintlayout. Here's the working code which produces exact same output as of your image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cross"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_clear_24" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/dostuff"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cross">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adding Image in landscape mode of the above layout:
[image]